# Existing IIS virtual directory on-premise doesn't update but throws error while deployed using Azure release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a IIS Web App Manage step which throws an error
Configuration Type: IIS Virtual Directory
Parent Website Name: Default Web Site
Virtual Path: /virtual directory name
Physical Path: location of the files in disk

When I delete the virtual directory under the website in on-premise and run this step it works but when the virtual directory already exists it throughs an error

This is the error:

> 2023-02-02T21:54:06.4773028Z ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer
> for VDIR object with verb SET. ) 2023-02-02T21:54:06.6837602Z
> ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '50'.

How do I get this working without deleting the virtual directory every time I have to deploy

I tried to running Azure Release Pipeline successfully but it fails when the Virtual Directory exists

Comment: I ended up removing this step
You set it up one time manually and that is sufficient, if you don't set it up in CICD.